# Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим (количественно-именное сочетание)

Tags: грамматика, согласование, единственное-множественное-число, счетный-оборот

*В банке **лежало** сто тысяч.

В банке **лежали** сто тысяч.*

Как я понимаю, возможны оба варианта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **2.** Форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на совокупность предметов, форма множественного числа — на отдельные предметы. Ср.: *В городе **строится пять объектов** соцкультбыта* (единое нерасчлененное представление о действии). — *В крупнейших городах страны **строятся** еще **пять объектов** соцкультбыта* (расчлененное представление о действии). Ср. также: *В крендельной **работало двадцать шесть человек**...* (Горький). *— **Восемь самолетов** полка **взлетали** попарно, соблюдая очередь* (Н. Чуковский). Поэтому при подлежащем, обозначающем большое число предметов и воспринимаемом как одно целое, сказуемое обычно ставится в единственном числе, например: *В столовой в одну смену **сидело сто человек*** (Макаренко); ***Прибыло шестьсот студентов-путейцев*** (Н. Островский).

Да, здесь возможны оба варианта. И поиск дал почти равные результаты:
*лежал**о** сто тысяч* — 497, *лежал**и** сто тысяч* — 439.

Но я заметила, что если речь идет о безналичных деньгах, то чаще всего используется единственное число сказуемого:
*До дурацкой Горбачевской перестройки у него на сберкнижке **лежало** сто тысяч рублей* (Владимир Шитов. Собор без крестов);
*На депозите у нее **лежало** сто тысяч рублей, а доходность составляла 7% годовых* (из статьи);
*Месяц назад у нее на счету **лежало** сто тысяч, да и то недолго* (Джон Сэндфорд. Глаза убийцы).

Если же имеются в виду наличные, то — множественное:
*Но ведь кроме моего мужа никто не знал шифра, а там **лежали** сто тысяч...* (Эрл Гарднер. Дело беглой медсестры);
*Меньше чем через тридцать минут Сычев вышел из здания коммерческого банка Люксембурга. В его кейсе **лежали** сто тысяч долларов: четырнадцать пачек с купюрами разного достоинства* (Сергей Москвин. Акция возмездия).

[§184. Сказуемое при подлежащем — количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091268.html#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20(%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).)

Answer (score 1):

Здесь возможны два вида согласования: как смысловое (ед. ч.), так как указывается пассивное состояние, так и формально-грамматическое (мн. ч.).